# Data Grid for Angular 2

Tags: angular, grid, ngtable

What data grid should be used for an Angular 2 project if performance is a concern?

I have been using `ng-table` for Angular 1, but am unsure which one would be good in terms of performance for Angular 2.

Comment: I'm not aware of any benchmark of every existent grid components for angular2, you will have to wait a little while until that happens. In the meantime this is the only grid component I know of https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2

Comment: I'm the author of https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table , I'd suggest giving it a shot! :)

Comment: I'm curious if you found any of these useful? I'm currently looking for a good Angular 2 grid that can handling Component loading in Cell, and movable row and column headers (currently can only find good examples of column move.)

Comment: You can take a look at [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) which I'm the author of. I would be happy to get feedback and contributions. I created it because I find that the available datagrid were far behind in terms of features compare to UI Grid which I was using in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one example of ng2-table.

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table 
Demo :- http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/

A recommended way to install ng2-table is through npm package manager using the following command:

```
npm i ng2-table --save
```

Below API used.

```
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';
```

or if you want to import specified plugins (Table component is required, the others are optional):

```
import { NgTableComponent, NgTableFilteringDirective, NgTablePagingDirective, NgTableSortingDirective } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';
```

Comment: I would suggest devextreme dx-grid. Very flexible and with high performance. For commercial use you have to buy it..